# Is it better to use "a" or "the" here in my book?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I have a peculiar situation, I am not sure whether to use "a" or "the" in my book. This takes place in a footnote of the title of the work that I mention.

> Mario wrote the work "Principia de mathematica"[1] in 1920.
>
> [1] The titles of the work contain "principiae", "principea" and "prinkepia";
>   **a/the** title with "prinkepia", for example, is provided in the work "Buhaha" by John Firaldo in p.23.

That is - there are many variations of this work's title. Then I provide an example of one of these titles.

So should I write "a title" or "the title"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The* is used to refer to specific or particular nouns; *a/an* is used to modify non-specific or non-particular nouns.

If you were referencing a specific title, you would want to use *the*.

Comment: So... are you saying I should use "a"? Because I never mention that "title" before, on the other hand I say that it has a particular word in it - so that is kind of like "specifying" it.

Comment: I would say that you should use "the," since you're referring to a specific word in a specific use.

Comment: @drozzy No, I am suggesting you use _the_, as it is referring to "prinkepia" in your example: _The_ title **with "prinkepia"**... An example of using _a_ would be "A title was selected at random." in which you are referencing no specific title.

Comment: @drozzy Another example would be if you were talking about four books that contained "prinkepia" in the title and two books that contained "principiae". You could then select "_a_ title with 'prinkepia'" because that would refer to any of the four books.

Answer (score 4):

If it is the **only** title with *prinkepia* in it, use *the*, otherwise use *a*.

**Edit**

It might be easier to say:

> The work is known by titles that use "principiae", "principea" and "prinkepia"; for example, "prinkepia" is used in the work "Buhaha" by John Firaldo in p.23.

Comment: I would say that it is the only title with that word in it, for that particular work.

Comment: So there are other titles, in other works, that use that word?

Comment: Maybe, but I am only concerned with the titles of "this" work - the first part of footnote indicates this, I hope.

Comment: In that case this is the only title with that word in it.

Comment: @Drozzy: Matt is right. Of all the titles of this work, the is *the* title that contains "prinkepia"; there is only one title of this work that contains it. (An ugly bastardisation, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to my fake word?